# Replaying SQL Server 2000 traces in SQL Profiler 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I am running SQL Profiler (the one that comes as a part of 2008 package) for a TSQL_replay trace on a SQL Server 2000 Standard edition database. When I try to open the resulting XML file for a replay, it pops up the following message: "Failed to read file data. File may be corrupt or it may have a wrong data format".

After that, Profiler is able to open a file and seems okay, but the replay options are grayed out.

Is it possible to play traces made on SQL Server 2000 databases within SQL Profiler 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may need to patch your 2000 instance: [FIX: Access Violation Occurs When You Use SQL Profiler or SQL Trace](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308723).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it does not work for me. According to aforementioned link "Microsoft has confirmed that this is a problem in Microsoft SQL Server 2000. This problem was first corrected in Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Service Pack 2.". I have got Standard Edition SP4.

Comment: You might try importing the trace into ClearTrace (http://www.scalesql.com/cleartrace/) and then into 2008.

Comment: Just tried ClearTrace. No luck, it says:"An error occurred reading the trace file. Error: Failed to read next event. Done."

Comment: Can you open it in your Sql 2000 profiler instance? If not, then it's just a bad trace.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. But I can see it is a problem with ALL traces created within SQL Server Profiler 2008 environment on SQL Server 2000 database. If I create traces on SQL Server 2008 database it works perfectly well. Moreover after error message occurs xml file is opened anyway, so I can see it content not broken.

Comment: I have found what the problem was. When trace is created within SQL Server Profiler 2008 environment on SQL Server 2000 database it should be saved as "Trace file" (.trc), not "Trace XML file for Replay" (.xml). In this way it can be reopened and replayed successfully in SQL Server Profiler 2008. It might have got something to do with the fact SQL Server Profiler 2000 does not work with xml files. Anyway @Chris B. Behrens I have found your comments extremely helpful.